# Oom kills with sdl2

Tags: c, sdl-2

code:

```c
#include"global.h"
#include"tools/entity.h"
#include"tools/input.c"
static const int width = 800;
static const int height = 600;
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    int init = IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    if((init & IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG) {
        printf("Couldnt load images :P");
    }   
    // Create the window
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Ferengine",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    // renderer
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);    
//  SDL_Surface * image = IMG_Load("funnyman.png");
//  if(!image) { printf("Could not load image because : %s\n",IMG_GetError()); }
//  SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);
    // settings
/*  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,0,0,255);
    SDL_SetWindowOpacity(window,1.0f);
*/
    
    entity2D player;
    player.posx = 0;
    player.posy = 0;
    player.sprite = "funnyman.png";
    int speed = 100;
    // loop 
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while(running) 
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }   
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
//  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    drawImage("funnyman.png",renderer,10,10,100,100);
    drawEntity(player,renderer,100,100);
    switch(getKeyPressed()) {
        case SDLK_w:
            player.posy += 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_s:
            player.posy -= 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_d:
            player.posx += 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_a:
            player.posx -= 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_q:
            running = false;
        default:
            break;
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }
    // release resources
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

when I run this (I wrote some stuff to draw entity's and images) it works and the character moves but when I don't move for a while it just closes the window
also if you were wondering getKeyPressed() returns an int(because sdlkeycode is an int)
so when I run gcc -o
Build/Ferengine
Source/main.c
-lSDL2
-lSDL2_image
-ldl
It kills with an oom (out of memory) error due to an image loading every frame,I fixed this by preloading the image before drawing it

Comment: No, you don't get OOM because you *draw* every frame, you (most likely) get OOM because you *load a new texture* every frame (without clearing the previous one). You should be loading the image once and then drawing it (every frame).

Comment: you're right guess I have to rewrite drawentity lol

Comment: *"fixed it mods please delete"* This is not how it works. You should summarize the solution you found in an answer below, to help anyone else who stumbles upon this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat alright

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing everything except for draw to only run once
https://pastebin.com/Lu44Majk

```c
#include"../global.h" // includes sdl,sdl2_image, and std libraries
void unloadImage(SDL_Texture * texture) {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}
SDL_Rect dstrect;
SDL_Rect srcrect;
int initImgSys() {
    int init = IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    if((init & IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG) {
        printf("Couldnt init SDL2_image do you have it installed?");
    }
    return 0;
}
SDL_Surface *loadImage (char *filename) {
 
    SDL_Surface * image = IMG_Load(filename);
    if(!image) { printf("Could not load image because : %s\n",IMG_GetError()); EXIT_FAILURE; }
 
    return image;
}
SDL_Texture *createImageTexture(SDL_Surface * image,SDL_Renderer * rend) {
    SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, image);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    return texture;
}
int drawImage (SDL_Texture *texture,SDL_Renderer *rend,int posx,int posy,int width,int height) {
    dstrect.x = posx;
    dstrect.y= posy;
    dstrect.w = width;
    dstrect.h = height;
    SDL_RenderCopy(rend, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            unloadImage(texture);
            IMG_Quit();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example:
https://pastebin.com/d3aUJiPA

```c
#include"global.h"
#include"tools/entity.h" // has image.h included
#include"tools/input.c"
static const int width = 800;
static const int height = 600;
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    int init = IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    if((init & IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG) {
        printf("Couldnt load images :P");
    }   
    // Create the window
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Ferengine",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    // renderer
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);    
//  SDL_Surface * image = IMG_Load("funnyman.png");
//  if(!image) { printf("Could not load image because : %s\n",IMG_GetError()); }
//  SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);
    // settings
/*  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,255,0,0,255);
    SDL_SetWindowOpacity(window,1.0f);
*/
   // create sprites
    SDL_Surface * funnyman_surface = loadImage("funnyman.png");
    SDL_Texture * funnyman = createImageTexture(funnyman_surface,renderer);
    entity2D player;
    player.posx = 0;
    player.posy = 0;
    player.sprite = funnyman;
    int speed = 100;
 
    // loop 
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while(running) 
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }   
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
//  SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    switch(getKeyPressed()) {
        case SDLK_w:
            player.posy += 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_s:
            player.posy -= 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_d:
            player.posx += 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_a:
            player.posx -= 1 * speed;
            break;
        case SDLK_q:
            running = false;
        default:
            break;
    }
 
  drawImage(funnyman,renderer,0,12,100,100);
  drawEntity(player,renderer,100,100);
       SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
 
    }
    // release resources
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely running out of memory and getting [OOM killed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory#Out_of_memory_management), probably because your `drawImage()` (which you didn't include here) is reloading the texture from file every frame.

Comment: but when I move drawimage out of the while statement it doesnt draw but this solution seems to work other than that